# Equivalent to Razor Section Helper In Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, sitecore

I am trying to include different scripts on different pages in Sitecore and can't seem to find a very good way of doing this. In a normal mvc project I could add the @Section{} helper and use that on different partial views to specify where I want those scripts in the layout view, but I haven't been able to find an equivalent for the way that Razor helper is implemented with Sitecore. I'd like to do this without using a place holder, I don't want to add a view in Sitecore every time I need to add a script file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have it setup in my current Sitecore MVC solution is my layout has an extension method call to RenderScripts() at the bottom before the closing body tag.

```
@Html.RenderScripts()
```

That extension method looks like this:

```
public static IHtmlString RenderScripts(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
       var templates = (from object key in htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Keys 
                        where key.ToString().StartsWith("_script_") 
                        select htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[key]).OfType<Func<object, HelperResult>>()
                            .Select(template => template(null)).ToList();
        foreach (var template in templates)
        {
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(template);
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
```

Then on each MVC Razor View when I want to include a .js file that is specific to that rendering I call something like below at the bottom of the file:

```
        @Html.Script(
        @<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/custom/orderdetail.js?t=11172015")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    )
```

Below is the Script extension method:

```
        public static MvcHtmlString Script(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> template)
    {
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["_script_" + Guid.NewGuid()] = template;
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
```

This has worked out well for us and I think it is what you are trying to do.

Comment: nice! this question is a bit old.. but I appreciate you taking the time to answer it

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you're out of luck here.
`@Section` is not supported because Sitecore doesn't render the Razor views in the same way as MVC does.
A Sitecore MVC layout is basically just a regular view that is rendering several other partial views or controller actions.

So when the placeholders in the `<body>` of your layout view are being rendered, the `<head>` section of that layout has already been rendered.
There is no such thing as deferred rendering in Sitecore MVC like you can do with `@Section`.

Everything in the view is executed from top to bottom, so if you can put your scripts at the end of your layout (like before the `</body>`), you can still manipulate data in the views or actions that are executed earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the Section-helper isn't supported in Sitecore. If you're using MVC4 you can maybe use Bundles to solve your problem. For more information see: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification
You can also create multiple bundles for specific views. In a single Bundle you can add multiple script and output it in your view by adding     @Scripts.Render()